# How to make an argument give a value to a variable?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a saveload function using the shelve module. This is my code so far.

```
def sl(value=None,var,loadvar=None,s_l):
    global loadvar
    gamedata=shelve.open('game')
    if s_l=='s':
        gamedata[var]=value
        gamedata.close()
    if s_l=='l':
        loadvar=gamedata.get(var)
        gamedata.close()
```

So how do I get the function to give the value that it gets in this line`loadvar=gamedata.get(var)` to the variable outside the function(the variable name is entered as loadvar)
For example there is a variable named as variable1 and i have a value stored in the gamedata file under the name v.
I then run the function as follows:

```
sl(v,variable1,l)
```

Now the value of variable1 should be equal to v.
How do i do this?

Comment: `return loadvar`?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. returning to outsite the function using `return loadvar` and outside the function

   ```
   variable = sl(v,variable1,l)
   ```
2. you can use `globals()`

   ```
   def sl(value=None,var,loadvar=None,s_l):
       global loadvar
       gamedata=shelve.open('game')
       if s_l=='s':
           gamedata[var]=value
           gamedata.close()
       if s_l=='l':
           globals()['loadvar']=gamedata.get(var)
           gamedata.close()
   ```

   then outside the function after its call you can use `loadvars` anywhere

Comment: Thank you! the solution using return worked though the second solution is raising an error-'SyntaxError: name 'loadvar' is parameter and global'

Comment: becouse loadvar is a system function you should change to other name and instance it before function `var = None` then `globals()['var']=gamedata.get(var)`